# Apache segfaults due to PHP

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

When running a particular piece of PHP code I am getting a segmentation fault in Apache2. The exact error is `Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.` After enabling core dumps and using `sudo gdb apache2 -core /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump/core` to analyze the core dump I got the result which can be obtained here http://pastebin.com/WetihWU0. Apparently something goes wrong with `spl_array.c`.

I narrowed it down to a piece of PHP code which uses a method generated by Propel 1.7. The piece of code removes a crossreference entry of a particular class:

```
foreach($record->getCrossReferences() as $crossReference) {
    $record->removeCrossReference($crossReference);
}
```

The error does not occur if I call `removeCrossReference()` outside the loop. Weird eh?

Since PHP crashes on some c code I find it hard to obtain a minimal code sample which produces the segfault. Does anyone happen to know what causes the segfault? Or maybe give me some pointers towards getting a minimal code sample? I don't think the guys at PHP.org accept a bug report without a minimal code sample.

Versions I use:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 20:05:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:38:21

Propel version 1.7.0-dev
```

Interesting fact is that I also have an Arch machine with newer versions of Apache and PHP. On this machine the fault does not occur. But I don't know if this is due to newer versions or different configurations between the Arch and Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Hard to say. While it would be interesting to know what happens here I guess the folks at php.net will tell you: "upgrade"

Comment: Do you have the php sources in their proper place? (As expected by gdb?)

Comment: @hek2mgl is right. as one of "folks at php.net" I can only ask you to upgrade. 5.3.10 is ancient and a lot of bugs were fixes since its release

Comment: @JimiDini Have changed to "folks" Seems that this sounds better in english.. srry :)

Comment: The problem also is I have to convince our host to also upgrade php. The problem also happens at our host. They are also using PHP 5.3.10. If I can't show them with a minimal example that they should upgrade I am going nowhere.

Comment: I had same problems too and can understand your situation. Does the problem occur on your host too? (Maybe it's a problem with an extension which is present on your dev box but not at the host)

Comment: @meijuh I can only suggest you to get a VM with newer version of ubuntu (or just backport newer php) and test your code there. this will give you a hint if upgrade fixes it

Comment: List of changes to `spl_array.c`: https://github.com/php/php-src/commits/PHP-5.3/ext/spl/spl_array.c

Comment: @JimiDini, I still haven't worked out a minimal example, but it seems very well that commit #321f4f18e fixes some segfault. I asked our host if they can upgrade their PHP version.